# Invalid syntax problem with Python (running pygame)

Tags: python, syntax, vector

I've been using The New Boston tutorial (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x9M3R6igH2E) on how to program with pygame and I keep getting an "invalid syntax" error on the print self.diff command. Only the self is highlighted. Here is the code (i've bolded the problem):

class vector(object):

```
def __init__(self, list1, list2):
    self.diff=(list2[0]-list1[0], list2[1]-list1[1])
    print **self**.diff
```

a =(20.0, 25.0)
b =(40.0, 55.0)
thing=vector(a,b)

Comment: Did you mean for `**self**` to be bolded?

Comment: Please fix your indentation.  It's impossible to tell what the problem is with improperly indented code.  Also.  What are the `**` doing in the code sample?  Please post the **actual** code you **actually** got the error on.

Answer (score 2):

Python 3? If so, arguments to `print` must be enclosed in parentheses: `print(self.diff)`.

If your learning materials and tutorials are based on the Python 2.x branch, you won't be too lucky with Python 3. Otherwise it's a great choice because it cleans up with many of the issues of the older Python versions.